# Restarting/Reusing a loop to iterate through an array with different parameters in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

Say I have the following array:

```
const myQuestions = [
      { 
      question: ...,
         ...
      difficulty: 2,
        ...
    },
    {
      question: ...,
        ...
      difficulty: 1
        ...
      },
      {
        question: ...,
         ...
        difficulty: 3,
          ...
      }
      etc...
    ];
```

And I want to iterate through the array in such a manner that I want to pick the first question found that has difficulty 3, which is the highest difficulty in this array.

I iterate through the array like so:

```
var currentcount=0;
var tempcount=currentcount;
var currentdiff=myQuestions[currentcount].difficulty;
 for(tempcount;tempcount<myQuestions.length;tempcount++){
    if(currentdiff<=myQuestions[tempcount].difficulty){
            currentcount=tempcount;
            break;
          }
```

Once I find the next question with the matching difficulty I am looking for, I remove it from the array:

```
myQuestions.splice(currentcount,1)
```

I then want to grab the next question with the next highest difficulty, which is still 3 because it is the highest difficulty. However, there are no more questions of difficulty 3 left in the array, so the next highest difficulty is 2.

How would I be able to reuse my for-loop (or any other loop for that matter) so that it searches through the same array with the new criteria of looking for questions of difficulty 2, and so forth with questions of difficulty 1 when all the questions of difficulty 2 are exhausted?

My guess is that I would need to update currentdiff if I reach the end of the array and still haven't found anything, and then also set tempcount back to 0 at the end of the loop as well.

My best guess has been this so far, but it doesn't work as intended:

```
var currentcount=0;
var tempcount=currentcount;

//keeps track of the current difficulty
var currentdiff=myQuestions[currentcount].difficulty;

        for(tempcount;tempcount<myQuestions.length;tempcount++){
         if(currentdiff<=myQuestions[tempcount].difficulty){
            currentcount=tempcount;
            break;  //stop the loop as the next question with the matching difficulty is found
          }
          else{
              //overallcount is the number of questions that have been grabbed and spliced so far
              //initially overallcount=0.
              //if not reached the end of the array, skip the rest of the statements and start the loop again from the next iteration
            if(overallcount<myQuestions.length){
              continue;
            }
            else if(currentdiff==3){
              currentdiff=2;
              tempcount=0;
            }
            else if(currentdiff==2){
              currentdiff=1;
              tempcount=0;
            }
            else{
             //if overallcount>=myQuestions.length, then the array is empty, so break the loop
              break;
            }
          }
        }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm having a little difficulty figuring out exactly what you want to do. It seems that you simply want to be able to successively pull out the element with the highest remaining difficulty? In that case, why not simply `sort` the array by that property? Then you can just go through them in order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) the questions before looping through them, like so:

```js
let myQuestions = [{
    question: '',
    difficulty: 2,
  },
  {
    question: '',
    difficulty: 1,
  },
  {
    question: '',
    difficulty: 3,
  },
];

myQuestions.sort(function(questionA, questionB) {
  return questionB.difficulty - questionA.difficulty;
});

console.log(myQuestions);
```